# css background image not displaying in html table

Tags: html, css

i have added this style to a `table`

```css
background-image:url(square_image.png); background-size:auto; background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

However the image is not being displayed in the background.

The demo Jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j03mp8bc)

Comment: make a jsfiddle :)

Comment: You are missing inverted commas on square_image.png **background-image:url('square_image.png');**

Comment: check here - https://jsfiddle.net/j03mp8bc/

Comment: also with inverted commas - https://jsfiddle.net/j03mp8bc/1/

Comment: Any browser today will understand it without the inverted commas.

Comment: the idea of it, is so its behind the text and also rotated 80 deg

Comment: this is the right idea - https://jsfiddle.net/j03mp8bc/11/ but i would like it behind the text as a background image and have the ability to rotate the image too

Comment: check my ans :) fixed it

Comment: not quite - @dippas is on the correct track

Comment: To just rotate the background-image isn't possible. Work with absolute elements.

Comment: would it be best to create the image rotated then just use it as a normal background image

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're having two inline "style" attributes.

Your updated code should be like:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="width:100%; min-width:500px; max-width:700px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;">
<tr>
  <td><table width="240" height="300px" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial;background-image:url('https://s32.postimg.org/wi1c9sm3p/Integra_Icons_Square_on_orange.jpg'); background-size:auto; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                    <td align="right">Text</td>
                  </tr>
              </table></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j03mp8bc/8/

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to use multiple attributes in HTML. 
Validate your HTML before asking on StackOverflow.
https://validator.w3.org/

https://jsfiddle.net/ou366bh7/

```
style=""
```